# SSL URL Masking

Tags: ssl

I'm working on a travel agency website where the results are provided by a data provider on another domain.
So each search on our site will send data request to the other domain.
For example user select departure, destination & dates on abc.com, but the search results page are on second domain like:

```
www.xyz.com?city=Mtl&DepartureTime=01/2/2016&destination=NY
```

We do not have any control on xyz.com , however we have complete control on abc.com
What I need to do is to prevent users to see the xyz.com the URL while searching for results.

Is that possible through SSL masking? 
Is there any way at all of doing this? if so how?
I would like to avoid using iframe/frames if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The URL bar will show the URL of the loaded page. There is no way to make the URL bar display something else, so any URL's you don't want to show must be

- either embedded with an iframe. Note that sites can easily deny such embedding by technical means and might even break out of the iframe (frame buster).
- or your server need to proxy the site somehow so that your server is accessing the site in behave of the user and that you display the results behind your own URL. Note that this is technically far from trivial because all links on the proxied site need to be rewritten. And you might also get legal problems because you display somebody else content as your own.